# Why doesn't "instanceof" work correctly when I use the same module as the Express application during end-to-end testing in Jest?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I'm implementing an application in `NodeJs` using the `Express` server. I want to test one of the middleware `globalErrorHandler` in the form of end-to-end tests. To do this, I run the application using `Jest` and send requests to it using the `supertest` library.

For testing purposes, I created an additional router to simulate different error cases that should be handled properly by my handler.

This is what my error handling middleware code looks like:

```
// global-error.handler.ts

import express from 'express';
import { HttpStatusCode } from 'axios';
import { appLogger } from '../config/logger.config';
import { HttpException } from '../exceptions/http.exception';

export const globalErrorHandler = (
    err: Error,
    _req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction,
) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpException) {
        appLogger.error('Http exception occurred:', err);
        res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
    } else {
        appLogger.error('Unexpected error occurred:', err);
        res.status(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError).send('An unexpected error occurred');
    }
    next();
}
```

And here's the test code:

```
// global-error.handler.spec.ts

import request from 'supertest';
import { HttpStatusCode } from 'axios';
import { Router } from 'express';
import { HttpException } from '../exceptions/http.exception';

beforeAll(() => {
    const testRouter = Router();

    testRouter.get('/http-exception', () => {
        throw new HttpException({
            message: 'Some http exception',
            statusCode: HttpStatusCode.ImATeapot,
        });
    });

    // trust me, it works
    registerRouter(testRouter, '/test');
});

describe('global error handler', () => {

    it('should handle http exception and return response', async () => {
        const response = await request(ctx.app).get('/test/http-exception');
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(HttpStatusCode.ImATeapot);
        expect(response.text).toBe('Some http exception');
    });
    
})
```

The problem is that the status code returned in the test response is `500`, along with the message `An unexpected error occurred`. The reason for this is that `err instanceof HttpException` returns `false`.

When I register the same router in the application at the time of its launch (using `app.use(...)`), the code works correctly. It seems that the reference to `HttpException` used in global-error.handler.ts differs from the reference to the same class in `global-error.handler.spec.ts`.

What is the cause of this problem? Is it possible within Jest or any other testing framework for such a prepared test to work correctly?